# How to get entropy value of any input file?

Tags: c#, entropy

Are there any built-in methods in `C#` that calculate `entropy` or is there some formula I can use? I've looked around, but cannot find anything regarding C# file entropy.

**Additional Details:**

I have `mean`, `median`, `mode`, and `standard deviation` of a file, but I'm not sure what to do about the `entropy`.

If this helps, it is an encrypted file by **Shift Cipher (Caesar Cipher)** with Z<sub>256</sub>.

Comment: @AlexBell - I don't understand the answer to that question. It doesn't seem to be C#.

Comment: @Khaltazar It's pseudo-code. You should be able to extract C# code from it.

Comment: I agree with @EBrown: the generic solution is provided, so please write your own C# implementation and bring us your code if there is any problem. Kind regards,

Comment: "Are there any built-in methods in C# that calculate entropy" - nope.  Seems like you already have the formula you can use in the generic solution.